# Make domain point to a directory in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 domains and I would like to route them to different directories in the same S3 bucket

```
domain1.com > s3-bucket/domain1
domain2.com > s3-bucket/domain2
```

is this possible? I couldn't find anything.

do I need to route all oF them to a single location (like a lambda function) and somehow redirect to a bucket directory?

Comment: Use two S3 buckets.

Comment: Not with S3 alone, but you can do this with Cloudfront. The CDN also allows you to use https with a s3 static website and custom domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Cloudfront to do what you want.

- You need to create 2 Cloudfront distributions, 1 for each domain you have.
- Configure each distribution with the same s3 bucket as the origin. In the origin path, put /domain1 and /domain2 for the 2 distributions.
- Set Alternate Domain Names as domain1.com and domain2.com respectively
- Provision DNS records to CNAME to the cloudfront's URL (xyz.cloudfront.net)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

DNS names resolve to an IP address. There is no way to indicate a Folder via a domain name.

Also, Amazon S3 requires that Bucket names match the Domain name. See: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)